# Qemu-kvm using virt-viewer vs remote-viewer

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt

Host: Ubuntu 18.04
Guest: Ubuntu 10.04

I started a virtual machine with the following command line:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 G.qcow2 -m 4096 -smp 4 -no-acpi -enable-kvm   \
  -name system76 -device virtio-net,netdev=net0                  \
  -netdev tap,id=net0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no,br=br0 \
  -vga qxl -spice port=5900,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing     &
```

I can access the guest with the following command:

```
remote-viewer spice://127.0.0.1:5900 # from the user (not root)
```

But I cannot access it with:

```
virt-viewer spice://127.0.0.1:5900 # from the user (not root)
```

This shows a pop-up window that says:

```
Failed to connect: No virtual machine found
```

or

```
virt-viewer -c libvirtd:///system system76
```

This shows a pop-up window that says:

```
Unable to connect to libvirt with URI libvirtd:///system
```

Although that is precisely what `virt-admin`, `uri` reports (from root).

So how do I connect with `virt-viewer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qemu-system-x86_64` command does not need `libvirt` to be enabled or installed in order to execute a VM. It uses QEMU/KVM only. So apparently you don't have `libvirt` enabled or installed on your host system. That's perfectly fine, but `virt-viewer` won't work, because it depends on `libvirt`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`virt-viewer spice://root@127.0.0.1:5900`

or

`sudo virt-viewer spice://127.0.0.1:5900`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use `virt-viewer -fw system76` to connect to my VMs.

`-f` is to open it in full screen

`-w` virt-viewer will wait that the VM is correctly turned on

`system76` is just the name of the VM

PS : I use a script to open my VM so the -w flag is to avoid virt-viewer to open while VM isn't loaded yet. Without the -f flag the VM will open in windowed mode

Comment: So, are you saying that the `-w` flag makes the difference? Does it work for you if you leave out the ``f``?

Comment: I use a script to open my VM so the `-w` flag is to avoid virt-viewer to open while VM isn't loaded yet. Without the `-f` flag the VM will open in windowed mode

Comment: Please edit your original answer to add the supporting information from your comment.